# how to build a url by getting the parameter from the behind code file?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose I have a page named:`test.aspx`,and a behind code file `test.aspx.cs`.

Now ,inside the test.aspx,there is a frame whose "src" attribute is dynamic:

```
<iframe src="anotherPage.aspx?id=<%=id%>" xxx>
```

the id parameter is to be explosed by the cs file
Then in the cs:

I have a protected field named id:

```
protected strin id;
```

But it seems that it does not work?

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using expressions in ASP .NET, it is **[always advisable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)** to use **properties instead of public fields**.

With auto-implemented properties things are even simpler in C#.

See if the following helps:

```
<iframe src="anotherPage.aspx?id=<%= ID %>" xxx>
```

and the code behind declaration would be:

```
public string ID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"protected strin id";
```

should be

```
public string id;
```

Comment: (and ideally make it an int if your ids are integers - type safety is good!)